# Running program(s) - nothing happens

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, buildpath

I've been having problems running a project, and others in Eclipse.

I was mainly developing plugins before this, so it's been a while since I've done a stand-alone project. Maybe I'm just forgetting about something? =/

When I "run as" "java application" in Eclipse, absolutely nothing happens with no console output, too.

I have a guess that I am using the wrong buildpath (although I never changed it.)

Here is a screenshot of all the options:

[List of Java Execution Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx4ti.png)

Which one should I choose?

Since this is happening to all my projects, I thought there would be no need to post project-specific code. If I was wrong in thinking that, please inform me and I'll post it.

Sorry for the huge question, first time asking on here...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project are you working on? I mean: is it a command line application? If that is the case, then your application should have a class with a main method.

Comment: It's a simple GUI program containing, of course, the main method.

Comment: Then J2SE is ok. I would check the signature of the main method: `public static void main(String [] args)`.

Comment: Here's my main method:

 `public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Spacewar!");
        Content content = new Content();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setSize(600,480);
        window.setLocation(100,100);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        System.out.println("Debug");
 }`

Comment: The main seems to be fine. But there is something strange with your screenshot: the package icon is white when I think it should be brown. I think that is related to the build path. Could share a screenshot of the build path?

Comment: That is the classpath, not the buildpath. Check this please: http://screencast.com/t/ggBLmvnwmx

Comment: Nothing wrong there. Given you are running on Windows, I think there could be an issue with the "!" in the name of your project. I would try to create a new Java Project and just a a simple class with main that prints "hello", just to check that you environment is properly setup. Avoid any "strange" character in names.

Comment: Hhmmm, I would have never thought that would be the problem.... Wait, it's happening for my other projects, too. Would one incorrectly-named project break them all? =D

Comment: I just refactored it, no difference.

Comment: Sometimes there are issues about "strange" characters. But I think the issue this time is related to your environment. Do the following check. Close Eclispse an open it again but create a new Workspace. Once there, create a simplemente project like I mentioned: just a class with a Main method to perform a System.out.println

Comment: Well, I got as far as the first step - http://imgur.com/jVABsYL
It's been "saving workspace" for about 15 minutes. Although it doesn't seem to be responding, I'm scared to close it and lose all of the work I've done today. I think I'll be switching to IntelliJ IDEA soon... lol

Comment: It deleted the whole project. Well, problem solved I guess. Dang.